# What is this function with a question mark doing?

Tags: android

What is this function doing specially the question mark after getAction()?

```
String strAction = !MyRUtils.isNullOrEmpty(getIntent().getAction()) ? getIntent() .getAction() : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns the action's intent if the action is not null nor empty,   otherwise it returns an empty String.

It can also be written like this.

```
String strAction;
if(getIntent().getAction() == null || getIntent().getAction().isEmpty()) {
   strAction = "";
} else {
   strAction = getIntent().getAction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `?:` is called the [ternary operator](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018:).

Your code line

```
String strAction = !MyRUtils.isNullOrEmpty(getIntent().getAction()) 
         ? getIntent() .getAction() 
         : "";
```

is equivalent to this:

```
String strAction = null;
if (!MyRUtils.isNullOrEmpty(getIntent().getAction()) {
     strAction = getIntent().getAction();
} else {
     strAction = "";
}
```

As you see it's just some syntactic sugar, which can be used to avoid the verbose if-else block.